# How do I delete rows in one CSV based on rows in another CSV using specific columns to compare

Tags: python, loops, csv, compare

I have two CSV files, `CSV1` and `CSV2`, with multiple columns and rows. One of the columns is titled `ID`.

What I want to do is check `CSV1`'s rows and if there is an `ID` in `CSV2`'s `ID` column that matches `CSV1`'s rows `ID`, then I want to keep that row. If there's no match, then I want to delete the row from `CSV1`.

Basically the data in `CSV1` is relevant to me, but only the people that are in `CSV2`. The unique connection between the two is the `ID` column. So I need to check all the rows in `CSV1` to see if that Row `ID` is in a row in `CSV2`.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import csv
smarteeCSV = open("Smartee.csv", "r")
aeriesCSV = open("aeriesEditable.csv", "r+")

aeries = csv.reader(aeriesCSV, delimiter=',')##CSV1
smartee = csv.reader(smarteeCSV, delimiter=',')##CSV2    

for row in aeries:
    for item in smartee
    if row[1] != item[1]##indexes for the columns with the ids
```

I can already tell I'm not on the right track, so can anyone assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract all of the ID's in the second file and look those up every time you check one of the rows of the first file.

For example:

```
# extract ID column from CSV file 2 into a set
Ids = { row[1] for row in smartee }

# pick only rows whose ID is in Ids 
filtered_rows = [item for item in aeries if item[1] in Ids]
```

Comment: Ids would be better as a set, 0(1) as opposed to linear

Comment: No worries, won't matter on small input but will be much more efficient dealing with large input.

Comment: You all are Gods among men!

Worked Perfect and exactly how I want it to. You rock!!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you plan on doing with the relevant rows of data, you might be able to use Python's built-in [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) function to do what you need:

```
import csv

# first get the ids    
with open('Smartee.csv', 'rb') as smarteeCSV:  # CSV2
    ids = set(row['ID'] for row in csv.DictReader(smarteeCSV, delimiter=','))

with open('aeriesEditable.csv', 'rb') as aeriesCSV:  # CSV1
    relevant = filter(lambda row: if row['ID'] in ids,
                        csv.DictReader(aeriesCSV, delimiter=','))

# relevant will be a list containing the desired rows from CSV1
```

If you want to iteratively process the rows, for the second part you could use a `for` loop over the results of calling the [`itertools.ifilter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) function similarly instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, read CSV2 to make just a set of IDs:

```
with open(CSV2) as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    theids = set(row['ID'] for row in r)
```

Then, while reading CSV1, just check if the ID is in the set:

```
with open(CSV1) as f, open(CSV1 + '.new', 'w') as out:
    r = csv.DictReader(r)
    w = csv.DictWriter(out, r.fieldnames)
    for row in r:
        if row['ID'] in theids:
            w.writerow(row)
```

This assumes the CSV files are suitable for dict-based read/write (i.e first row is a list of column names), but is easy to tweak if the col names come from other information too.